# If I have a function that randomly creates shapes, how can I add those shapes to a group? (CMU CS Academy)

Tags: python, function, shapes, group

I'm working in CMU CS Academy's Sandbox and I currently have a function that will draw a rectangle of random size, color, and position:

```
# List of colors
app.colors = ['crimson', 'gold', 'dodgerBlue', 'mediumPurple']

# Creating random shapes
import random

# Draws a random rectangle with random points for size and center along with a random color
def drawRect(x, y):
    color = random.choice(app.colors)
    x = random.randint(5,390)
    y = random.randint(15,300)
    w = random.randint(10,40)
    h = random.randint(10,40)
    r = Rect(x,y,w,h,fill=color,border='dimGray')
    x = r.centerX
    y = r.centerY

# Draws multiple random rectangles
def drawRects():
    for i in range(5):
        x = 50 * i
        y = 60 * i
        drawRect(x,y)
drawRects()
```

However, I want to add all the random rectangles that the function draws to a group so that I'm able to use the .hitsShape() method.

I also thought about creating a list with the random x and y values, but I'm not sure how to create a list with coordinates in CS Academy. What should I do to my current code? What should I do next?

Comment: Please use multiline code block. This is hard to read. You can do that by wrapping your snippets into triple `

Comment: I realized that I messed that up as soon as I posted it--sorry. Fixing that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have forgotten to end your functions with `return ...`. That way, you can keep working with this data further in the code block. It's one of "best practices" in Python.

Also, I'm assuming you mean a collection by "group"?

You could save them in a tuple in this manner:

```py
def drawRect(x, y):
    ...
    r = Rect(x,y,w,h,fill=color,border='dimGray')
    ...
    return r

def drawRects():
    my_shapes = []
    for i in range(5):
        x = 50 * i
        y = 60 * i
        my_shapes.append(drawRect(x,y))
    return my_shapes
```